# Delay in connecting to a new database

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework

I am planning to make a software (ASP.NET 4.6.1 MVC with Entity Framework), which does a lot of reading from DB. Therefor I have one database, which contains all global information, projects etc. and now I am thinking to either bring all the content into the same DB but in different tables or to create a DB for each bigger group.

Now as there is a lot of reading going on, is it bad practise to have the connection information in the main db and then to connect to a different DB? Otherwise I would have the project information in the primary database and the content in a different table on the same DB.

Are there any notable delays to connect to a different DB to retrive the information?

Answer (score 0):

If it's all *your* data, for your application, it should all go in the *same* database. Definitely use different tables. You should read up on entity design and normalization... and if you really need to do that, you may already be in over your head.

Comment: Well it's planned that various companies can use the software. So I was thinking about the option to have one DB for each company, but keep all primary information (the metadata for projects and connection info) in the primary database

Comment: What you're talking about now is [multi-tenancy.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx)